# Unable to get when user dennied activating location - React Native Geolocation Service

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I am opening this question and answering it myself to help other users that face the same issue.

Working with a React Native app in Android that uses the package *[react-native-geolocation-service](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service)*, when trying to get the user to activate its location (not to allow it, to **activate it**), I found that the button cancel wasn't returning any errors. Here is the pop up I'm talking about:

[image]

The function I was using was the following:

```
   Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
         console.log(position);
        (error) => {
          console.log(error.code, error.message);
        },
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
    });
```

I was completely sure it was correct, because it was a copy from github's repo. But then, the console never logged the error.

If you are facing the same issue, check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the problem was that a combination of Visual Studio Code pluggins (Prettier and ESLint probably) messed up with my code. The correct code should look like this:

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      pos => {
        // Do somehting if location activated
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error.code, error.message);
      },
      {enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000}
    );
```

As you can see, all of my previous code was inside the *"pos*" brackets, meaning that it was only entering if it was successfull. Since the error block could never get reached, I wasn't able to get the negative answer from the user.

Hope this was of use to anyone.